# Using FixedWindows on data without GroupBy

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have a streaming pipeline which consumes events tagged with timestamps. All I want to do is to batch them into FixedWindows of 1 min each and then, write all events in a window into a single GCS file. I can use `FixedWindows` except that from the documentation, I can see that I need a `GroupBy` or `Combine` operation to have the windowing applied, but for my use case, Windowing has already done all the grouping I require. I see two possible solutions for this, both of which I am not sure are ideal

- Push these items into a single `GlobalWindow` and apply a 1-minute trigger repeatedly, discarding fired panes. I have not tried this yet and I am not sure if this will work without a groupBy
- Run a global `Combine` operation after the `FixedWindow` - I am not sure if this will still take the windows into account or not.

  Is any of these the right choice or is there anything better that can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, I want to address your goal: It sounds like you would like to group all of the values in a particular window. For this, you will need a `GroupByKey` or `Combine` (to do the grouping or aggregation, not really anything to do with windowing).

A global `Combine` will take the window into account. The best way to think about Dataflow's transforms is that they all operate primarily *within* a window.

I also want to comment on some other aspects of your post:

- Actually, for non-merging window like `FixedWindows` the window will be applied immediately at the `Window.into(FixedWindow.of(Duration.standardMinutes(1)))` transform.
- A trigger such as `AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane(Duration.standardMinutes(1))` will not do what you want - it represents an approximate timeout. On a per-key basis, at some reasonable moment *after* one minute of local time after the first element arrives, whatever is buffered will be emitted. It will not correspond to one minute of event time, or any particular event time or arrival time window.